# Facebook blocked person - can they see my reactions to posts?

Tags: facebook

If I block someone on Facebook he cannot see my posts, I can't see his and we cannot message each other, but what about my posts/comments/reactions on other people's posts or pages? Is the block related only to posts on my timeline or all posts anywhere? What about my reactions to someone else's posts, can that person see them or they get filtered out?

For example I like a friend's photo and it's his friend too, so will he see that I liked that photo?

Answer (score 1):

No, once you block someone, that person would not able to see any of your activity.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/168009843260943?ref=u2u):

> When you block someone they will no longer be able to do things such as tag you or see things you post on your timeline.

Comment: sorry, but I am really not sure about it, because I have seen this sentence as well and it is definitely not so specific as you interpret it. Not able to do things "such as" is not very precise definitions and they mention things I post on my timeline, so I don't know if liking someone else's photo counts into this definition, because I don't "post it" on my timeline...

Comment: You can test it easily if someone has blocked you. Or ask any of your friends to block you for testing purpose.